# How do I convert this query into a paramatized query in classic ASP?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

My website suffers from SQL injection attacks. My web developer refuses to acknowledge paramatized queries saying his escape script is sufficient.  Can someone please help by showing how to convert the following query written in classic asp into a paramatized query?

```
conn.Execute "insert into tblGROUPcomments ([thecomment], [date_of_entry], [groupid], [submittedby]) " _
            & "values ('" _
            & Server.HTMLEncode(cleanuptext(request.form("txtcomments"))) & _
            "','" & FormatMediumDate(date()) & _
            "','" & session("groupid") & _
            "','" & session("userid") & "')"
            session("errmessageT") = ""
            session("varcommentT") = ""
    response.redirect("../showallcommentsGROUPS.asp?gid=" & session("groupid")) & "#comments"
```

Comment: What flavour of SQL? Is this SQL Server, oracle, IBM? And also which version might help a bit too. Also what is the "escape script"?

Comment: Did you search at all?  If you search for something like 'Preventing SQL Injections in ASP' you will get several examples.  Like this one - [How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

Comment: Apologies I did search but I will better understand if someone shows me how to convert one of my queries. Apologies once more.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse Its Microsoft SQL Server 2008 . The escape script is his own.  A custom made script.

Answer (score 1):

First create command object like below

```
 Dim cmd
 Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 ' set command to your previously opened connection
 Set cmd .ActiveConnection = connContent
 SQL = " insert into tblGROUPcomments ([thecomment], [date_of_entry]) values (?, ?)"

 Set newParameter = cmd.CreateParameter("@thecomment", ad_nVarChar, ad_ParamInput, Server.HTMLEncode(cleanuptext(request.form("txtcomments"))), thecomment)
   cmd.Parameters.Append newParameter
 Set newParameter = cmdConn.CreateParameter("@date_of_entry", ad_Integer, ad_ParamInput, FormatMediumDate(date()), date_of_entry)
     cmdConn.Parameters.Append newParameter

 cmd.CommandText = SQL
 cmd.Execute
```

I have used just 2 columns(thecomment and data_of_entry) in query. Just modify column types in the newParameter. There may be syntax issue which i guess you can easily solve. If after you complete your parameterized query get  any error then please contact. 
Hope you got the starting point.

Comment: Ash my web developer says this is desktop development. Not web based. Is he right?

Comment: i can see that he has written response.redirect in his code then to me it is web development

Comment: No sorry Ash.  My web developer says your code is desktop development. Is he right?

Comment: I gave the answer based on his question. His code doesnt seems to be desktop one. Its web based as he is using response.redirect. Ask him to correct the question if he thinks answer is not correct

Answer (score 0):

```
    maxCommentSize=1073741823
    comments=Server.HTMLEncode(cleanuptext(request.form("txtcomments")
    comments=left(comments,maxCommentSize)

    Set cmdAdd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
    cmdAdd.ActiveConnection = connection_string
    cmdAdd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO nsert into tblGROUPcomments ([thecomment], [date_of_entry], [groupid], [submittedby]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)" 
    cmdAdd.Prepared = true
    cmdAdd.Parameters.Append cmdAdd.CreateParameter("param1", 203, 1, maxCommentSize, comments) 
    cmdAdd.Parameters.Append cmdAdd.CreateParameter("param2", 135, 1, -1, FormatMediumDate(date())) 
    cmdAdd.Parameters.Append cmdAdd.CreateParameter("param2", 5, 1, -1, session("groupid")) 
    cmdAdd.Parameters.Append cmdAdd.CreateParameter("param2", 5, 1, -1, session("userid")) 
    cmdAdd.Execute
    cmdAdd.ActiveConnection.Close

    session("errmessageT") = ""
    session("varcommentT") = ""
    response.redirect("../showallcommentsGROUPS.asp?gid=" & session("groupid")) & "#comments"
```